# Why in the last episode did no one question Hank Henshaw's being able to protect his own mind?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl, supergirl-2015

In the last episode, Hank Henshaw appears to be in a room with Cat Grant and Maxwell Lord when they were giving a message of hope. He had not had on any protection around his head or ears which would have protected him from the mind control.

Wouldn't Maxwell or Cat question this? Although he's an alien who can protect his mind, doesn't that expose him?

Comment: I assume you mean the last episode of season 1?

Comment: Isn't his identity as the Martian Manhunter public knowledge at this point? He shifted back into Henshaw in front of everyone before giving himself up.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Max and Cat each have *different* reasons not to suspect that there's anything amiss about Hank being able to protect his mind.

### Max

At this point in the show, Hank has **already revealed himself as an alien** (at the end of Episode 15; [Falling](http://supergirl.wikia.com/wiki/Falling)). It can be reasonably assumed that given Maxwell Lord's deep penetration of the DEO that he's very well aware of Hank's non-human heritage and the reason for his leaving his post.

> **Max:** *Once Henshaw and his Trusted Girl Friday stepped down, I had no one at
>   the DEO to trust.*

It would therefore be no surprise to him that Hank isn't affected.

### Cat

Supergirl is busily outlining her plan to defeat the Myriad signal with a message of hope. Alex then arrives (with her mother and Hank, neither of whom are wearing magic earrings) and confirms that defeating the signal is actually pretty simple and doesn't require technology.

> **Alex:** *And then my mother said something about my father and it was like a
>   switch went off in my brain.*

Cat has no reason to believe that Hank hasn't had the same kind of mind-cleansing done to him that's been done to protect Alex and Eliza Danvers.